# 64-bit ubuntu 12.04.5 iso file for I5 NUC

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit

I got an NUC i5 core assembled. Want to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (need that specific version for ROS HYDRO robot). Now looking at what Ubuntu image to pick. Selected the PC (Intel x86) desktop.iso image. But see that it is a 32 bit OS type when starting from USB. The other image I can select is 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop CD giving me an AMD64.iso. Is that only for AMD 64-bit processor? Where is the 64 bit x86 image?

This is the text from the releases.ubuntu.com/precise website:

There are two images available, each for a different type of computer:

PC (Intel x86) desktop CD
For almost all PCs. This includes most machines with Intel/AMD/etc type processors and almost all computers that run Microsoft Windows, as well as newer Apple Macintosh systems based on Intel processors. Choose this if you are at all unsure.
64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop CD
Choose this to take full advantage of computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2). If you have a non-64-bit processor made by AMD, or if you need full support for 32-bit code, use the Intel x86 images instead.

Note also when I select 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS from the main ubuntu page to download (on an intell machine) it collects the desktop-amd64.iso file to download?

Where do I get the 64-bit ubuntu 12.04.5 iso file for I5 NUC?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. 
http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/AMD64.html
You have to pick AMD64 iso. There is no other 64 bits.